Confluent Kafka Topic Authorization Failed
I was using a .sh script to login into confluent Kafka using a username and password, then try to update the config of a topic. Here, am able to login into Kafka. However, getting error while doing this step:
confluent Kafka topic update ${TOPIC_NAME} --config "retention.ms=0"

The error is Error: REST request failed: Topic Authorization failed.
And then logged out. I am not a Kafka expert and there is a team for that. They told that the required access is given. What all things should a Kafka team check for?

This isn't a Kafka error. There is some HTTP authentication server in-between that is denying the request

Just an update on this, it's actually the Kafka team missed to make the user account as resource owner to this particular topic. Once they did it resolved the issue.
